# regex to find specific tags contain some tags

Tags: php, regex

[sorry about my topic and topic title, i don't have enough time to learn PHP DOM now]
How to capture `a` tags, contain some text and tags?
for example:

```
<div>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google COM</a>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.co.uk/">Google <span class="country">UK</span></a>
</div>
<span>
<a id="italy" href="http://www.google.it/"><span class="country">Italy</span><strong> I</strong></a>
<a class="link" href="#top">Top</a>
</span>
```

i want to capture `a`, which contains `Italy` or `Google`.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Regex is not good for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 - and it's certainly harder than using DOM.

Answer (score 5):

[PHPDOM<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) really is the easiest tool to use here, the selector/expression syntax isn't that hard:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html); # your string
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);   

$xpath->query("//a[text()[contains(., 'Italy') or contains(., 'Google')]]");
```

If you only want to look in a certain parent element, you can add it easily:

```
$xpath->query("//div/a[text()[contains(., 'Italy') or contains(., 'Google')]]");
```

Comment: thanks, but when i run your script (http://pastebin.com/pwWAPgf5), it says: `Warning: DOMXPath::query() [domxpath.query]: Invalid expression in`.

Comment: There was an extra ']' on the end of the expression.  Check now.